# ComponentOne WPF RichTextBox not handling AddPastingHandler or AddCopyingHandler correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, copy-paste, componentone

I am trying to prevent copy/paste within a ComponentOne WPF RichTextBox. I have read that the following code should work for WPF controls:

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(EditorBox, OnCancelCommand);
DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(EditorBox, OnCancelCommand);

private void OnCancelCommand(object sender, DataObjectEventArgs e)
{
    e.CancelCommand();
}
```

where `EditorBox` is a `C1.WPF.RichTextBox.C1RichTextBox`.

This works fine for the other WPF controls we are using, but not for the ComponentOne RichTextBox. What happens is that the copy action is not handled by the event handler, and copy works as normal. The paste action is handled, but the text is still pasted anyway, so `e.CancelCommand()` has no effect.

Is this a problem peculiar to the ComponentOne RichTextBox control?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734350/c1richtextbox-with-custom-copy-paste-behavior, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle the PreviewKeyDown event and check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.